# How to run Azure Storage Emulator on remote machine when no user is logged in

Tags: azure, windows-server

I have a web application on one of the client's machines (a virtual machine running Windows Server 2012R2). The application uses Azure Storage. For testing purposes it was decided to use an Azure Storage Emulator.

My problem is that, when I log out of the remote machine the storage emulator stops. How do I keep the Azure Storage Emulator running even if no user is logged in?

Comment: Are you logging out or just closing the RDP session window?
Logging out will shut down any application running on the virtual desktop. closing the window via the X symbol  would not shut down apps. If your emulator stops, what massage was shown in the CMD?

Comment: this case may be helpful to you: https://serverfault.com/questions/269438/how-to-stop-remote-desktop-from-closing-my-session-due-to-inactivity

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Thank you for your suggestions. Firstly, I know that logging out will shut down any application. I was hoping to simulate the Azure Storage Emulator as a service and keep it running. Secondly, I ended up just disconnecting and not logging out. I didn't try what the post in your second comment suggests, but it should work being based on just disconnecting.